# Installed latest ruby on mac but still showing old in terminal

Tags: ruby, bash, cocoapods, homebrew, homebrew-cask

```
Installed latest ruby but still showing old version
```

I have installed latest ruby version on mac ventura and getting success message
Successfully installed ruby 3.2.2 into /Users/myuser/.rubies/ruby-3.2.2

But when checking ruby --version on the same or new terminal Then i am still getting old one
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin22]

i have exported below files in bash_profile

```
source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh 

source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh

export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
```

Can anyone please suggest why the latest version is not reflecting on search ruby --version.

On search, "ruby --version" we should get latest installed ruby 3.2.2 but still showing 2.6

Comment: Usually it is bad idea to use system Ruby on the local machine. It's better to use asdf, rvm, rbenv or other Ruby manager

Comment: It's also possible your shell is actually `zsh` in which case modifying bash configs will have no "effect".

Comment: ventura's default shell is zsh, use `.zshrc`

Comment: Did you check that your PATH variable really has `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin` as first component?

Answer (score 6):

When you try to install ruby via homebrew, it installs it "keg-only". [What does keg-only mean?](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#what-does-keg-only-mean) It means that it installs ruby only in homebrew's cellar, to avoid overriding the ruby that comes preinstalled with your system.

If you really want to, you can run `brew info ruby` to see instructions for how to add this keg-only ruby into your PATH and make it your default ruby. But that's **not recommended**!

It's **recommended to install a ruby version manager**, like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#seamlessly-manage-your-apps-ruby-environment-with-rbenv), [rvm](https://rvm.io/), or [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html). Then you'll be able to use that to install different ruby versions and switch between them and the system ruby seamlessly.

For example, here's how to install and use `rbenv` using homebrew:

```bash
# 1. Install rbenv and set it up:
brew install rbenv ruby-build
rbenv init
# - Follow the printed instructions to add rbenv to your PATH etc.
# - Close your terminal window and open a new one so your changes take effect.

# 2. Use rbenv to install the ruby version that you want
rbenv install 3.2.2

# 3. Set which ruby version you want to use. Two options:
rbenv global 3.2.2   # set the default Ruby version for this machine (simpler)
rbenv local 3.2.2    # set the Ruby version for this directory 

# 4. Verify that you're using the correct ruby version.
ruby -v
```

Here's more instructions for rbenv:

- [rbenv: Installing ruby versions](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions)
- [rbenv: Installing ruby gems](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-gems)
- [rbenv: Command reference](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#command-reference)

Comment: You also need to add  
eval "$(rbenv init - bash)"
to your bash startup.

Comment: Correct, thanks! It's part of the instructions that `rbenv init` prints out. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
rbenv init
rbenv install 3.3.0
rbenv global 3.3.0
rbenv local 3.3.0
eval "$(rbenv init - bash)"
ruby -v
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -3):

As suggested by @mechnicov in the comments, it is recommended to alter the system ruby. you can use the `asdf` package manager for it. here is the installation guide [link](https://mac.install.guide/ruby/6.html)

Comment: The comment I think you're referring to says "Usually it is bad idea to use system Ruby on the local machine". That's not a recommendation to alter the system Ruby, but rather a recommendation to install a different one alongside for one's own personal use.  Which happens to be exactly what the OP has done.